# SPDEs driven by fractional brownian noise

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes

I am looking for some references for the following kind of SPDEs

$$dX_t= AX_t\,\mathrm{d}t+BX_t\,\mathrm{d}W^H_t,$$
given $X(0)=X_0$, where $A$ and $B$ are operators and $W^H_t$ is the fractional Brownian motion with hurst index $H>1/2$. I am looking for well-posedness (mild/variational) results in the setting where the noise $W^H_t$ is treated in the path-wise sense (defined by Zähle). I am aware of some results where the authors consider the noise coefficient as an affine function, but, I do not know any results available for Lipschitz functions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  in the Da'Prato book "stochastic equations in infinite dimensions" in *"14.1.6 Equations with fractional Brownian motion"*, they go over some references. For example, they mention  "Evolution equations driven by a fractional
Brownian motion". Here they contain the Lipschitz-bounded case

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This result is very restrictive on the dimension. I was wondering if there have been any improvements on this front in last 20 years.